# Is there a way to interact with a shell but from an app or separate program?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, command-line, terminal

I am trying to find a way to both receive the output of a shell and then return output, but from a different front end interface? I am trying to incorporate the Linux terminal into a potential application.

Comment: Do you want to execute shell commands and process/return the output? Or do you want to provide a terminal interface to users inside your application?

Answer (score 0):

The controlling application needs to open two pipes, using pipe() twice. It then forks a child process.

While still in the original code, the parent closes the write end of one pipe, and the read end of the other.

Meanwhile, the child closes the opposite ends of those pipes, and uses dup2() to reassign those to streams 0 and 1. That leaves the parent with a pipe that writes to the child's stdin, and a pipe that reads from the child's stdout.

Finally, the child exec's the required shell with any args required.

Comment: I searched for a complete code but no joy. There are some issues in doing this: in particular, you need some flow control to avoid deadlock, where the parent writes until both pipes are full without reading anything back from the client.

Comment: I found a Bash+awk script that managed a complete DB Schema (creation, data load, reporting, etc). In a four-year project, it grew to 1250 lines after 78 versions. It created two names pipes, and assigned them like `exec 8>"${F_CMD}" 9<"${F_LOG}"` to run an sql background session like `/bin/bash -c "${SQL}" <"${F_CMD}" >"${F_LOG}" 2>&1 &`. Then the script just threw SQL into `1>&8` and read back results from `0<&9`. For flow control, each command set ended with `select '<><><><>COMPLETE<><><><>' from dual` and it read the return pipe until it found that text response.

Comment: @Paul: What you describe looks interesting. Can we have a closer look at the script or thesis or project page you're referring to ? ...

Answer (score 0):

`expect` is the tool. Read `man expect` https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Rather than a "Thank you" comment, click on the checkmark to "accept" my answer.